# Role based router in Express Js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, routes, roles

I am developing a e-commerce system that have 3 different roles : admin, client and customer, which admin and client can access via website for system management (Any CRUD process) and customer view the content on their mobile. So basically, admin and client can't login to mobile using their id and password and vice versa for the customer. The mobile app is design with React Native, which means customer just use the API to retrieve data or update data to the db.

Regarding to the router design for Express Js(let's take login as an example), should I :

1. Design my router for example `app.use('/api/login')` for both user type to login and decide the page or API to redirect by using middle-ware to determine the role (which means I will need to add a new table for role in MySQL db).
2. Handle router separately,  `app.use('/api/admin/login')` for admin and client, and `app.use('/api/user/login')` for user. So if via web page, it will called the `/api/admin/login` API and for the mobile it will call the `/api/user/login`.

for better organization of my code.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You could use dynamic routes. Depending upon platform.

Comment: What do you mean by not possible?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. You want to first login then query db to identify is user a admin or client. Then redirect to any route?

Comment: Currently I am not designing a table for role in MySQL, as I am not sure that is this the best practice for my cases. So my idea is, if user login via mobile, it will call the /api/user/login for account authorization, else if via website, it will call the /api/admin/login as well. Which means by default, if someone login via website, it will classified as an admin or client, if mobile app, then it will be a customer. That's the reason I design 2 different table for admin and customer in MySQL, so each authorization will refer to its own table only.

Comment: If the user login from website, it will check the admin table, if via mobile, it will check the user table (Id, email, etc...)

Comment: I think the admin table idea makes sense so all users log in the same and then you can go to the admin login route which only stores the admins inside of it giving them extra permissions to access the full CRUD.

Comment: make a role.js file and export all your role like this `module.exports = {SUPER_ADMIN:'SUPER_ADMIN', CLIENT: 'CLIENT',CUSTOMER:'CUSTOMER'}` and import this file whenever you want to use it Or you can create new table for role if you know that you have to add more role in future